# Comparing index 0 in array with all other indexes

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexing

If I want to compare index 0 with index 1, 2 and 3 for instance, how is that possible?

```
boolean iftrue = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (IntValue(array[j]) == IntValue(array[i + j])) {
                iftrue = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return iftrue;
}
```

Comment: Store the element at index 0 in some variable. Compare all other indices to that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put Sotirios' suggestion into code... Recall he suggested you save the first elem and compare other elements against it.

```
  public boolean sameAsFirstElem(int[] array) {
        boolean isEqual = false;
        int firstElem = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == firstElem) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take 0th element is an variable and go on searching from 1st index onward. If you find the match stop else go all the way upto end of the array and report that match not found. This can be done in linear time O(N) where N is the size of the array. No need to have two loops and hence increase the time complexity to O(N^2)

```
 boolean sameAsFirstElem(Object[] array) {
    boolean isEqual = false; //Assume match will not be there, if we come across any,
                             // we will set it  to true
    int firstElement = IntValue(array[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (IntValue(array[i]) == firstElement) {
            isEqual = true; //Indicating that match has found
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

I am assuming that IntValue(Object) return int, and hence the `int firstElement`, and taking Object as a parameter.